# Где можно посмотреть исходники STL C++?

Tags: c++, stl

Откуда можно посмотреть исходный код STL в C++, перерыл папку компилятора, но кроме хедеров ничего не нашел.

Comment: Хедера это и есть исходники. Это библиотека шаблонов, шаблоны распространяются в заголовках.

Comment: STL в классическом понимании термина -чисто шаблонная библиотека. Она вся в хедерах и сидит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходники libc++ от clang есть в svn:

`svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk libcxx`

Исходники libstdc++ от gcc можно найти [тут](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3) (по большей части  интересны каталоги include и src). Большая часть библиотеки находится в заголовочных файлах.

Answer (score 0):

Так вы внимательно посмотрите - это на 90% и есть исходники - там же сплошные шаблоны.